# Does Firebase Firestore allow for dynamic variables in secondary queries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am attempting to make a fairly basic set of queries, where the second builds on the results of the first.

```
const fetchWatchlist = async (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {

  // fetch the watchlist according to the logged in user
  const watchlist = admin.firestore().collection('userdata').doc(request.userData.uid).collection('watchlist');

  const movieIds: string[] = [];
  const snapshot: admin.firestore.QuerySnapshot = await watchlist.get();
  snapshot.forEach((doc: admin.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) => {
    const watchlistItem: any = doc.data();
    movieIds.push(watchlistItem.movie_id);
  });

  // fetch movies matching watchlist
  const movies = admin.firestore().collection('movies').where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', movieIds);
  const moviesSnapshot: admin.firestore.QuerySnapshot = await movies.get();

  const ret: Movie[] = [];
  moviesSnapshot.forEach((doc: admin.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) => {
    const movie: any = doc.data();
    ret.push({
      title: movie.title,
    });
  });

  return response.status(200).json({ data: ret });
}
```

The second query always returns an empty snapshot.

The problem can be isolated even further:

```
const fetchWatchlist = async (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {

  // fetch the watchlist according to the logged in user
  const watchlist = admin.firestore().collection('userdata').doc(request.userData.uid).collection('watchlist');

  // hardcode data to check if document ID is present in
  const test = ['1', '2'];

  // fetch movies matching watchlist
  const movies = admin.firestore().collection('movies').where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', test);
  const moviesSnapshot: admin.firestore.QuerySnapshot = await movies.get();
}
```

The following code *does* work

```
where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', ['1', '2']);
```

The following does not:

```
const test = ['1', '2'];
where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', [...test]);
```

The following only respects the last hardcoded value

```
const test = ['1', '2'];

// this will return a match for '3', not nothing else from test;'
where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', [...test, '3']);
```

This is running on google cloud functions (via firebase functions) with node 8.

Comment: Firestore doesn't care at all how you build the argument to a query.  JavaScript will determine its value before Firebase sees it.  The issue is entirely about what exactly you are passing to the API, and if that's going to yield what you want.

Comment: Which makes sense, however it’s not what I’m observing. If I remove the first async query, and simply provide the array into the second it works as expected. It’s behaving almost like there is an async issue, though I can see the array is populated.

Comment: It definitely sounds like an issue with asynchronous calls. I don't know where you see that the array is populated, but recommend `console.log(JSON.stringify(theArray))` as that prevents the environment from updating the output to an the updated value.

Comment: Aside from that: Doug is correct, this is a language-level issue. The Firestore SDK only sees the final value of your expanded array(s).

Comment: Sigh - Thank you guys, output to JSON allowed me to see a dreaded space at the beginning of the stored IDs that I could not see when outputting the array. Gotta love it.

So there is nothing wrong with the above, i simply kept copying the incorrect untrimmed values to my hardcoded arrays :(